# Updating ec2 instance name through user-data

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am launching a centos 7 ec2 instance, and I want to update my instance name in the EC2 Console to reflect a specific structure - and this needs to be done in the user data.

**What I tried so far:**

1. So I know you can update an instance name doing the following:

   ```
   aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-123 --tags Key=Name,Value="test"
   ```

However this means that aws must first be installed and I need an IAM role setup - which is something I do not want to do.

2. The ec2 instance is launched through the AWS console, so the name could be changed here 
   [image]

However the I want the name to look like this:
`$PRIVATE_DNS.testing.com` in the ec2 console:
[image]

Is this achievable using userdata?

Comment: not without a role or IAM credential

Comment: I agree with @hjpotter92 it is not possible without a role or IAM creds.  You need to rethink your tactics :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add tags like Key and Value that you mentioned above via user data there is way but you will need IAM Permission **ec2:CreateTags**.

```
instance_id=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="Your AWS Region"
/usr/bin/aws ec2 create-tags --resources $instance_id --tags'Key="abcde",Value=12345'`
```

Comment: Alternatively: `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep region | awk -F\" '{print $4}')`